# ‘min’ not meaningful for factors

Tags: r

```
Exchange_rate <-read.csv("Exchange.csv")

str(Exchange_rate)

summary(Exchange_rate)
weekdays = data.frame(wdy =c("Thu","Fri","Mon","Tue","Wed"),x =runif(5),y =runif(5))

summary(Exchange_rate$forecast)

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(gridExtra)

min(as.character(as.numeric(Exchange_rate$YYYYMMDD)), na.rm=TRUE)

normalize<-function(x){return((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))}

exchangeN<-as.data.frame(lapply(Exchange_rate, normalize)) //ERROR AT THIS LINE

summary(exchangeN)
```

I get the below error

> exchangeN<-as.data.frame(lapply(Exchange_rate, normalize))Error in Summary.factor(c(115L, 117L, 120L, 122L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 130L,  : ‘min’ not meaningful for factors

Why am I getting this and how do i fix this?

Comment: It looks like `exchangeN` is coded as a factor (a categorical variable) rather than as numeric, which is what is causing the error. Are there non-numeric values in that column? If so, when `read.csv` reads the data, it will code those columns as factor (or as character if you set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

`lapply(Exchange_rate, normalize)` is the same as `lapply(as.list(Exchange_rate), normalize)`; it applies `normalize` to every column. One of the columns is a factor. `str` should have told you which one(s).